# Atomically check owner, check mode and read file

Tags: node.js, security

I have an application that reads an IP and port from a file and then opens a HTTP connection to the address read. To be a little more sure that I'm connecting to the server I want to connect to I only want to trust the contents of the file if it's owned by root and not writable by anyone else.

I could check the owner and mode with `fs.stat` and then read the file contents but that would introduce a race condition.

Is there a way to atomically check the owner and the mode and read the file contents?

Answer (score -1):

I dont think that with `fs.stat` you are introducing a race condition because you are only reading it and not writing on it, so i think that the solution that you found is the best one, right now.
You can maybe add a boolean variable to check if a function is still "reading" the file (after reading should set the boolean), to avoid problems.

Comment: Thanks for answering! I was thinking that the race condition occurs if 

1. My node process runs `fs.stat`
2. Another process runs `chmod`
3. My node process reads the file contents

Comment: You cant control that, if the problem was a function in YOUR program you can solve it like i said before, with a check before messing with the file, otherwise you cant handle that stuff, its external from your code